# PHP multi upload images issue

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to code a script which makes it possible to upload multiple images. This is the code I'm working with.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_images'])) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($_FILES['file'] as $file) {
        $image = new Image();
        $image->member_id = $_POST['id'][$i];
        $image->image_type = "MedlemsBillede";
        $image->attach_file($_FILES['file']);
        if($image->save()) {
            $message = 'Billedet blev uploadet med succes.';
        } else {
            $message  = join("<br />", $image->errors);
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

My problem lies in this call to function:

```
$image->attach_file($_FILES['file']);
```

And that function looks like this:

```
public function attach_file($file) {
    if(!$file || empty($file) || !is_array($file)) {
        $this->errors[] = "Der blev ikke uploadet nogen fil.";
        return false;
    } elseif($file['error'] != 0) {
        $this->errors[] = $this->upload_errors[$file['error']];
        return false;
    } else {
        $this->temp_path    = $file['tmp_name'];
        $this->file_name    = str_replace(' ', '_', basename($file['name']));
        $this->file_type    = $file['type'];
        $this->file_size    = $file['size'];
        $this->ts   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Does anybody have an idea for how to fix this?

Comment: *My problem lies in this call to function* ... what is the problem ? any errors ? what happens when its executed ?

Comment: I'm not able to send to correct part of the array through to the attach_file function. It works when I'm only using the function for the uploading of one file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
$image->attach_file($_FILES['file']);
```

You are iterating over $_FILES['file'] rather than just $_FILES

Also you are the calling the array through which you are iterating inside the loop

The call should be like this

```
$image->attach_file($file);
```

May this help you

Comment: Yes I've tried that too but that gives me "Undefined index" errors on the following: error,tmp_name,name,type,size

Comment: you some debugging skills like try doing this print_r($_FILES) just to check what values the array contains

Comment: Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => cup32.png [1] => cardgame32.png [2] => boxdownload32.png ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/png [1] => image/png [2] => image/png ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpdkIp2J [1] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpKwtbda [2] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpquOEWC ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 433 [1] => 696 [2] => 1035 ) ) )